# Joomla com_jce exploit: What logs should I be looking in and what for?

Tags: linux, joomla, exploit

One of my 20+ sites has fallen victim to the COM_JCE exploit. I know the domain name and IP address it is attacking.

What log file should I be looking in to identify which site is being exploited.

This is what the complaining site sent me:

> Lines containing IP:xx.xx.xx.xx in
>   /furanet/sites/*/web/htdocs/logs/access
>
> /furanet/sites/cabrandalucia.com/web/htdocs/logs/access:xx.xx.xx.xx -
>   - [23/Mar/2014:00:18:30 +0100] "POST /index.php?option=com_jce&task=plugin&plugin=imgmanager&file=imgmanager&method=form&cid=20&6bc427c8a7981f4fe1f5ac65c1246b5f=cf6dd3cf1923c950586d0dd595c8e20b
>   HTTP/1.1" 404 1439 "-" "-" "BOT/0.1 (BOT for JCE)"

So my site is supposedly attacking: cabrandalucia.com

Comment: maybe `web/htdocs/logs/access/`